# Can I insert deserialized JSON SObjects from another Salesforce org into my org?

Tags: json, salesforce

We have the need to clone a complex data structure from one org to another. This contains a series of custom SObjects, including parents and children.

The flow would be the following. On origin org, we just JSON.serialize the list of SObjects we want to send. Then, on target org, we can JSON.deserialize that list of objects. So far so good.

The problem is that we cannot insert those SObjects directly, since they contain the origin org's IDs and Salesforce won't let us insert objects that already have Ids.

The solution we found is to manually insert the object hierarchy, maintaining a map of originId > targetId and fixing the relationships manually. However, we wonder if Salesforce provides an easier way to do such a thing, or someone knows a better way to do it.

Is there an embedded way in Salesforce to do this? Or are we stuck into a tedious manual process?

Answer (score 1):

`List.deepClone()` call with *preserveIds* = false might deal with one problem, then:

Consider using upsert operation to build the relationships for you.
Upsert not only can prevent duplicates but also [maintain hierarchies](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm).
You'll need an external Id field on the parent, not on the children though.

```
/* Prerequisites to run this example succesfully:
    - having a field Account_Number__c that will be marked as ext. id (you can't mark the standard one sadly)
    - having an account in the DB with such value (but the point of the example is to NOT query for it's Id)
*/
Account parent = new Account(Account_Number__c = 'A364325'); 
Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test', Account = parent);
upsert c;

System.debug(c);
System.debug([SELECT AccountId, Account.Account_Number__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c.Id]);
```

If you're not sure whether it will work for you - play with Data Loader's upsert function, might help to understand.

If you have more than 2 level hierarchy on the same sObject type I think you'd still have to upsert them in correct order though (or use `Database.upsert` version and keep on rerunning it for failed ones).