# Set up relation on two existing Salesforce objects

Tags: salesforce, relationship

I have a custom object in Salesforce which I need to setup a Master Detail relationship from Accounts.  Accounts being the Master and CompHist being the Detail.  The problem I am running into is that I need to set the relation to work off of custom fields within the objects. Example:

1.) Accounts has a custom field called CustomerId.

2.) CompHist also has custom field called CustomerId.

3.) I need to be able to have this linked together by CustomerId field for report generation.

About 2,000 records are inserted into CompHist around the 8th of each month.  This is done from a .NET application that kicks off at the scheduled time, collects info from our databases and then uploads that data to salesforce via the SOAP API.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how Salesforce relationships work as I am fairly new (couple months) to salesforce development.

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to get this to work without triggers that will link the records or pre-querying the SF to learn Account Ids in .NET before you'll push the CompHistories.

**Setup**

On Account: set the "External ID" checkbox on your CustomerId field. I'd recommend setting "Unique" too.

On CompHist: you'll need to make decision whether it's acceptable to move them around or when the relation to Account is set - it'll stay like that forever. When you've made that decision tick / untick the "reparentable master-detail" in the definition of your lookup / m-d to Account.

And if you have some Id on these details, something like "line item number" - consider making an Ext. Id. for them too. Might save your bacon some time in future when end user questions the report or you'll have to make some kind of "flush" and push all lines from .NET (will help you figure out what's to insert, what's to update).

*At this point it's useful to think how are you going to fill the missing data (all the nulls in the Ext. Id) field.*

---

**Actual establishing of the relationship**

If you have the external ids set it's pretty easy to tell salesforce to figure out the linking for you. The operation is called `upsert` (mix between `update` and `insert`) and can be used in 2 flavours.

"Basic" upsert is for create/update solving; means "*dear Salesforce, please save this CompHist record with MyId=1234. I don't know what's the Id in your database and frankly I don't care, go figure this out will ya?*"

- If there was no such record - 1 will be created.
- If there was exactly 1 match - it will be updated.
- If there were more than 1 found - SF won't know which one to update and throw error back at you (that's why marking as "unique" is a good idea. There's a chance you'll spot errors sooner).

"Advanced" upsert is for maintaining foreign keys, establishing lookups. "*Dear SF, please hook this CompHist up to Account which is marked as "ABZ123" in my DB. Did I mention I don't care about your Ids and I can't be bothered to query your database first prior to me uploading my stuff?*"

- Again - exact match - works as expected.
- 0 or 2 Accounts with same ext. id value = error.

---

**Code plz**

I'd recommend you to play with Data Loader or similar tool first to get a grasp. of what exactly happens, how to map fields and how to not be confused (these 2 flavours of upsert can be used at same time). Once you'll manage to push the changes the way you want you can modify your integration a bit.

SOAP API upsert: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm (C# example at the bottom)

REST API: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_upsert.htm

If you'd prefer an Salesforce Apex example: [Can I insert deserialized JSON SObjects from another Salesforce org into my org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909447/can-i-insert-deserialized-json-sobjects-from-another-salesforce-org-into-my-org)

Comment: So off the top of my head after reading your post I need to:

1.) Truncate CompHist object.
2.) Create relationship
3.) In my .NET app I need to query SF for the Salesforce ID of the Account.  Then when inserting data for that account I force Salesforce to use that ID when inserting data into CompHist?

Comment: That will basically link the custom ID's that I have but salesforce will still be using the ID it created for the Account?

Comment: Why would you want to delete any data from CompHist? You have the "CustomerId" on it and the lookup/master-detail to Account, right? Or are the fields not there yet? You could query SF for Account fields before inserting... but the whole point of my answer was to show you how you don't have to do that at all, how you can tell Salesforce to solve this matching for you.

Comment: I don't have time today but if you want we could make a chat session tomorrow evening (I'm on GMT)

Comment: I will take a look at the links you sent when I get time to today.  Yes, the both fields are in the objects that I need linked, but Salesforce is telling me I can't create master-detail without creating lookup relation first.  I'm sure you know what you are talking about and I am new to SF and probably over thinking things.  So a chat would be cool if you'd be willing to take a few minutes of your time (I'm EST -5 GMT)

Comment: Can you prepare for tomorrow then ;) I mean we shouldn't play in the production environment. Please create a "sandbox" (test salesforce environment that's copy of production but might have no data in it) if you don't have one already and check what you need to check in test version of your .NET app to connect to this sandbox

Comment: I have a sandbox but for some reason it doesn't pull accounts in.  But i upload a couple accounts and the corresponding CompHist.  What time my time is good for you tomorrow?  Do I need to create you an account in the sandbox?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43288/discussion-between-eyescream-and-randy-r)